# How can I put HTML in sublist field?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I want to add a link to a sublist field.
every line item will have different link

I tried with URL field but its just to put the link - I want to make the window small and put a img so i need html

```
 objSublist.addField({
            id: 'custpage_test',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            label: 'Test'
        });


        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {




            //Set URL
            newRec.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'custpage_serials',
                line: i,
                value: '<html lang="en"><body><a href="https://www.example.com">Web site</a></body></html>'
        
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can still use a URL field and make it show a "Label" text instead of the full url:

```
objSublist.addField({
    id: 'view',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.URL,
    label: 'View'
}).linkText = 'View'; // you will see a "View" text instead of the URL.
```

But the downside here, is that because the "linkText" attribute is defined on the Field level, then you can not have a different "linkText" for each value on each line.

If you need to have a different text for each line, then you can include more sophisticated HTML code by using a field of type TextArea : something like this:

```
objSublist.addField({
    id: 'appstepid',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXTAREA,
    label: 'ID'
});

objSublist.setSublistValue({
    id: 'appstepid',
    line: k,
    value: '<a target="_blank" href="' + appStepUrl + '">' + appStep.id + '</a>'
});
```

And if the sublist is editable, then the TextArea field must be set to be displayed Inline:

```
objSublist.addField({
    id: 'appstepid',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXTAREA,
    label: 'ID'
}).updateDisplayType({
    displayType : serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.INLINE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for sublists is like so:

```
const serialsField = record.addField({
        type: FieldType.SELECT,
        id: "custpage_serials",
        label: "Serials"
    });
    serialsField.addSelectOption({
        value: "url1,
        text: "URL 1",
        isSelected: true
    });
    serialsField.addSelectOption({
        value: "url2,
        text: "URL 2"
    });

etc...
```

Then you can add a client script to take sublist value, and use that to trigger window.open("my url") linking to a new page/tab